# Instagram Developer - Error 400, Invalid Client ID

Tags: instagram

My colleague has asked me to authorise our Instagram account onto an application we use. I've followed the steps we were provided, but when I try to authorise it, I get this error:

{"error_type": "oauthexception", "code": 400, "error_message": "invalid client id"}

I noticed a few other people had similar errors, so I tried a few different recommendations such as disabling implicit OAuth. However, these don't seem to work. Does anyone have any other ideas what this could be? The client ID has been entered correctly.

Thanks for any help anyone can offer!

Comment: Please share your code with us, what have you tried so far?